# Placing a method inside the args of another method?

Tags: php

I have these two lines:

```
pll__("No Coments"); ?>

<?php comments_number('No Comments','1 Comment','% Comments'); ?>
```

I want to replace the `'No Comments','1 Comment','% Comments'` part of the second method with `pll__("No Coments"), pll__("1 Coment")`, and so on.

I'm not sure what's the right way of doing it, specially with the last part (`'% Comments'`).

Comment: what represent pll_ function? what's doing this?

Comment: @Matei Mihai It's like `__();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that:

```
comments_number(pll__('No Comments'), pll__('1 Comment'), pll__('% Comments'));
```